# Testable ASP.NET architectures

Tags: architecture

I am looking for guidance on designing asp.net applications using n-tier architecture. Can anyone suggest architectures (not MVC) that use web-forms, and support modules and allow repeatable tests.

I understand the vagueness of the question, but am unsure of how else to put it.

A little more specifics : 
- Must use ASP.NET web forms.
- .NET 4.0 (not that the version really matters).
- I should be able to expose part of the business logic as services (if need be).

Comment: @ChrisLively: It's a framework specific question and therefore a SO question imho.

Comment: @jgauffin: It's a general question about program structure.  Not a specific question about issues implementing one.

Answer (score 1):

I have done Model-View-Presenter development with ASP.NET WebForms. This allows your logic to live in testable presenter classes. If you are stuck with WebForms, then this is an option.

When I did this, I rolled my own framework. But it looks like someone might have done the hard work for you.

http://haacked.com/archive/2006/08/08/ASP.NETSupervisingControllerModelViewPresenterFromSchematicToUnitTestsToCode.aspx

http://webformsmvp.com/

Comment: NerdFury, I am going to look at Haacked's site. That was my first instinct anyway. WebFormsMvp....i like what they have done, but am "trying" really hard not to use any third party tools (even if it is open source).

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

Only have presentation logic in the WebForms project and move all business logic into a class library. And test that class library.

Comment: Question then is ... how do you test the flow. It works for simple applications, but with complex ones, things start going haywire.

Comment: Unit tests do not test flow. They test that every single method works as their contract says.

Comment: jgauffin:  My apologies. I did not mean to indicate that unit tests are to test the flow.

Comment: Programs don't go haywire if every unit is tested and works as specified ;)

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the "framework" or patterns used, there's one thing that will ensure your application is testable: use test-driven development, so that your application will not *exist* except as a way to make unit tests pass.

Comment: John, I agree with you, and hence the dilemma of choosing a "way" to do things which allow complete test-ability.